# Past Perfect usage question

Tags: word-usage, tenses, sentence, past-tense, past-perfect

„Boxer Joe Foster had fought over 100 opponents when he retired in 1994.” Why someone used Past Perfect in this senence?

Comment: Note that because of the "when", if you use past simple instead, one might understand that in the moment of retirement he fought over 100 opponents.

Comment: Is there some reason that you're using nonstandard quotation marks? I see you did this in another question too. It looks quite strange.

Comment: Thank You very much for your help! I study English in my polish school 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is simple and was given in the comment. Fighting 100 opponents came before the 1994 retirement (we are in 2019 now). He had done that before he retired. That’s what the past perfect means and how it‘s used. It’s just basic grammar in most all languages I know of.